# When testing my snaptd start, it comes out as Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: c++

```
root@DESKTOP-O8V2BMI:~#  sudo service snaptd start
Failed to start snaptd.service: Transport endpoint is not connected
See system logs and 'systemctl status snaptd.service' for details.
root@DESKTOP-O8V2BMI:~# systemctl status snaptd.service
Failed to get properties: Transport endpoint is not connected
root@DESKTOP-O8V2BMI:~#
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some context - is this a regular Ubuntu system or WSL (perhaps WSL2)? What is the significance of the C++ tag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I know of no existent Ubuntu package that provides "snaptd" Please say where that service is coming from